# Javascript iterate over two-elements in a list when not concerned about result?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

Let's say I have a list like

```
let chain = [ 1, 9, 61, 798 ];
```

These are essentially denormalized nodes on a route, and I want to add the [edges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory_terms#edge) in a database. Ideally I'm looking for something that calls  `addEdge(node,parent)` for each two elements in the list. **I'm looking for the Ramda way of doing this.**

Does it bring any unique ability to the mix? I've thought of using something like `.reduceRight()` from core javascript,

```
[ 1, 9, 61, 798 ].reduceRight( (acc,v) => {
  addEdge(acc,v);
  return v
}, undefined );
```

But in this case, `.reduceRight` is returning something and seems weird to use that in void-context. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: While ScottChristopher's excellent-as-usual answer shows you *how* to do this, I think you might want to look again at *why* you want to do so.  Ramda is meant to help incorporate a functional style in JS.  A void `addEdge` function is not really useful in straight functional programming.  I don't know enough of your system to suggest alternatives and it's quite possible that there's no reason for any alternatives.  But a void function should be a red flag.

Comment: I agree, I could/should make the edge object immutable too but currently this isn't exposed to the user, and the api i expose returns an immutable object from the rest of the api's stance.

Comment: Makes sense.  One more question: is this (both yours and Scott's) the expected behavior?  Because to me the adjacent pairs don't really match with "for each two elements in the list."  It seems at least `[1, 61]` and `[9, 798]` are missing. And even if these represent some outer edge, shouldn't it also include the pair `[798, 1]`?

Comment: No, because a graph only ever shows the connection between two nodes, relationships aren't coded from children to great-great grand parents: that relationship is inferred. These are M.49 region codes (fyi) https://unstats.un.org/unsd/methodology/m49/ This is for a hierarchical and complete country code database which I intend to make public soon.

Comment: Ok.  While I don't follow entirely, if it works for you, great.  I look forward to seeing your completed work.

Comment: You should rely on `forEach` to make the side effect more obviously: `[1,9,61,798 ].forEach((x, i, xs) => xs[i + 1] !== undefined ? console.log(x, xs[i + 1]) : null);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`R.aperture`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#aperture) to produce a new array containing consecutive elements of a given size.

```js
const nodes = [1, 9, 61, 798]
const edges = R.aperture(2, nodes)

console.log(edges) //=> [[1, 9], [9, 61], [61, 798]]
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

You can then either `map` or `forEach` over the resulting array containing the pairs of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a vanilla JavaScript approach:

```js
const range = (from, to) => {
  const output = []

  for (let i = from; i < to; i++)
    output.push (i)

  return output
}

const pairize = xs =>
  range (0, xs.length - 1)
  .map (i => [xs[i], xs[i + 1]])


const nodes = [1, 9, 61, 798]
const edges = pairize (nodes)

console.log (edges)
```

Comment: You can also make use of the array index that is provided by `Array.prototype.map` such that your `pairize` function could look like `xs => xs.slice(1).map((x, i) => [xs[i], x])`

Comment: @ScottChristopher I know it, but I got used to the most abstract and generic `Functor#map` definition on which you wouldn't be able to use that index.